# bash, display only in case output has count of n characters

Tags: bash, grep, sed

how can I display content of output which has only count of **n** characters in second col divided by `,`? For example, grep only line which content 4 characters in second col.

Input.

```
a,123
b,223
c,1234
d,323
e,2234
```

Output.

```
c,1234
e,2234
```

Is some easy way to do this, for example by `cut` and `sed`, or `for` loop must be used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options:

```
grep ',....$' file

grep ',.\{4\}$' file

sed -n '/,....$/p' file

sed '/,....$/!d' file

sed -n '/,.\{4\}$/p' file

sed '/,.\{4\}$/!d' file

grep -E ',.{4}$' file

sed -En '/,.{4}$/p' file

sed -E '/,.{4}$/!d' file

gawk -F, 'length($2) == 4' file

perl -F, -lne 'print if length($F[1]) == 4' file
```

Comment: Thanks, and in case I need check **3rd** col divided by `,`?

Comment: OK, I know now. Thank you very much for answer.